# SQL Server Deadlock within WCF

Tags: sql-server, wcf, deadlock

I am trying to resolve a deadlock issue regarding a SQL transaction (which is in a stored procedure called via LINQ-to-SQL).  I used SQL Server Profiler and see that the SP is deadlocking on itself.

My client is calling a WCF method in rapid succession, which in turn calls the SP which causes a deadlock.

I have tried setting all the various SQL Server isolation levels as well as trying to set the WCF ConcurrencyMode = Single.

I continue to have many deadlock 'victims' and I am losing insert data as a consequence.

Has anybody solved this kind of problem?

Kind regards,
NickV

Comment: The solution will be in the design of your stored procedure. Can you post the code?

Comment: When you get a dead lock exception you should retry the transaction in your exception handler. While I agree with Paul Keister that the problem is probably in the stored procedure you need to handle deadlocks elegantly in your code. Retrying the transaction with a 500 ms delay will be a little more elegant than loosing data.

Answer (score 0):

To get details of the deadlock, switch traceflag 1204 on. Any time a deadlock occurs, the deadlock graph, including all the details on the contended resource and what the two processes were doing is written to the SQL error log. This really helps in finding the cases of the deadlock.

Keep transcations as small as possible. Do no unneccessary work in a transaction. Never begin a transaction then wait for user input. Ensure that queries within the transaction are as efficient as possible.

Access objects in the same order. If one proc updates tbl1 first, then tbl2 after, all other procs that use those two should use them in the same order. Done properly, this can prevent deadlocks completely.

Hope that helps